# I don't want to give a name to a key in a SQL statement in AWS IoT Rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot

I have a Lambda function returning a simple JSON:

```
{
  "serial": "ENLESS:70B3D5C76FEFF011",
  "temperature_c": 28.4,
  "account": "DSCVRY",
  "type": "enless",
  "rssi": -84
}
```

And this exactly what I need to POST to a HTTPS endpoint.

Unfortunately, it seems that on my SQL statement, I'm obliged to name my key:
[image]

This error got after I tried:

```
SELECT aws_lambda("arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:124915225239:function:EnlessDecode", {"PayloadData":PayloadData, "WirelessDeviceId": WirelessDeviceId, "WirelessMetadata": WirelessMetadata})
```

And if I do:

```
SELECT aws_lambda("arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:124915225239:function:EnlessDecode", {"PayloadData":PayloadData, "WirelessDeviceId": WirelessDeviceId, "WirelessMetadata": WirelessMetadata}) as body
```

I will have this JSON passed to my endpoint, not correct:

```
{ body : {
  "serial": "ENLESS:70B3D5C76FEFF011",
  "temperature_c": 28.4,
  "account": "DSCVRY",
  "type": "enless",
  "rssi": -84
}
}
```

In the AWS documentation, we can see examples without key names (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-select.html)

How can I avoid this naming? Or get the .body before passing to the endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. I went and read the AWS Docs and found that by using VALUE it was useful to extract/select items. I tested it and it worked to select the value from aws_lambda() function's response.

- [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-select.html#:~:text=You%20can%20use%20the%20%22VALUE%22](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-select.html#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20the%20%22VALUE%22)

SQL statement that worked for me:

```
SELECT VALUE aws_lambda("arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:123456789012:function:iot-parse-string", *) FROM 'parse'
```

SQL version

```
2016-03-23
```

---

To sum up, if I have IoT Rule's SQL statement using AS keyword as you did initially:

```
SELECT aws_lambda("arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:123456789012:function:iot-parse-string", *) AS output FROM 'parse'
```

It would have data output like this which is undesired:

```
{
  "output": {
    "data1": "1.0",
  }
}
```

However, if I use VALUE keyword without AS in SQL statement below:

```
SELECT VALUE aws_lambda("arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:123456789012:function:iot-parse-string", *) FROM 'parse'
```

SQL version

```
2016-03-23
```

I get the output I needed:

```
{
  "data1": "1.00"
}
```